# Laravel Follow System

Tags: laravel

I'm planning to use this [package](https://github.com/overtrue/laravel-follow) as it looks good for what I'm looking for. (it adds a user based follow system for Follows/Likes/Votes)

I have added the traits to my user model and professionals model as per their documentation and created a button on the professionals page:

```
<a href="{{ url('professionals/'.$professional->category->slug.'/'.$professional->slug.'/unfollow') }}" class="btn btn-sm white">UnFollow</a>

<a href="{{ url('professionals/'.$professional->category->slug.'/'.$professional->slug.'/unfollow') }}" class="btn btn-sm white">UnFollow</a>
```

I have defined the following in my routes file:

```
Route::post('professionals/{professionalcategory}/{slug}/follow', 'ProfessionalController@followProfessional')->name('professional.follow');

Route::post('proffessionals/{professionalcategory}/{slug}/unfollow', 'ProffessionalController@unFollowProfessional')->name('professional.unfollow');
```

And the following methods in my controller:

```
public function followProfessional($slug)
{
  $professional = Professional::where('slug', $slug)->first();
  $user = Auth::user();
  $user->follow($professional);
  return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'You are currently following this professional.');
}

    public function unFollowProfessional($slug)
{
  $professional = Professional::where('slug', $slug)->first();
  if(! $professional) {

     return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Professional does not exist.');
   }
  $user = Auth::user()->id;
  $user->follow($professional);
  return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Successfully unfollowed the professional.');
}
```

When I click on the follow button I receive this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

No message

My second question is:

I also would like to achieve the functionality where when a user clicks on "follow" and is added to the followers list, he should see a button "unfollow" instead of follow and vice versa.

I have tried:

```
@if($professional->isFollowedBy($user))
                <a href="{{ url('professionals/'.$professional->category->slug.'/'.$professional->slug.'/unfollow') }}" class="btn btn-sm white">Un Follow</a>
                @else
                <a href="{{ url('professionals/'.$professional->category->slug.'/'.$professional->slug.'/follow') }}" class="btn btn-sm white">Follow</a>
                @endif
```

But that doesn't work either. What is my mistake here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried the following code and it worked finally!

```
public function followProfessional(ProfessionalCategory $professionalcategory, $slug)
    {
      $professional = Professional::where('slug', $slug)->first();

      $user = Auth::user();
      $user->follow($professional);
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'You are now following this professional.');
    }


    public function unFollowProfessional(ProfessionalCategory $professionalcategory, $slug)
    {
      $professional = Professional::where('slug', $slug)->first();

      $user = Auth::user();
      $user->unfollow($professional);
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'You have unfollowed this professional.');
    }
```

and in the view

```
@if (Auth::user()->isFollowing($professional))
                    <a href="{{ url('professionals/'.$professional->category->slug.'/'.$professional->slug.'/unfollow') }}" class="btn btn-sm white">UnFollow</a>
                  @else
                    <a href="{{ url('professionals/'.$professional->category->slug.'/'.$professional->slug.'/follow') }}" class="btn btn-sm white">Follow</a>
                  @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting exception because your routes are post `Route::post()`

But you are calling these as a get.

change your routes lines to this.

```
Route::get('professionals/{professionalcategory}/{slug}/follow', 'ProfessionalController@followProfessional')->name('professional.follow');

Route::get('proffessionals/{professionalcategory}/{slug}/unfollow', 'ProffessionalController@unFollowProfessional')->name('professional.unfollow');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ah! That's right! I have changed it to get and it doesn't show a error now. But it doesn't add anything in the database. Is my controller code correct?

Comment: Now after changing the route from post to get, there are no errors shown. When i go to a professinal profile and click on follow button the page refreshes. But that doesn't add anything in the fable

Comment: @SrikanthGopi  try dd then

Comment: levaral Nothing happens with dd()

Answer (score 0):

For your second question.
You need to refresh the page if you want see the change of the follow/unfollow button after you click the button.

Otherwise if you want see the change of button immediately ,you need send an ajax request.And put the button text change code in the callback function.